# Pasted HTML code alignment is wrong

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you have an HTML page with aligned elements (eg, div, ul, li, p, etc) copying and pasting a chunk of these back into the same document will result in misaligned code.

This is a pain in the arse big time because you have to re-align the pasted code all the time. Am I missing some magical setting that would keep the indentation/alignment of the pasted code?

See attached image for an example.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an extensions installed? Try disabling them to see if one is causing this. Otherwise, please [file and issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) and we'll take a look

Comment: What seems to be the problem here? I don't see a formatting issue.

Comment: @ifcinfig Only people with attention to details can see it :-)

Comment: I had the identical settings and theme/extension packs on both machines except for one theme (Nord) which wasn't used. I disabled the Nord theme then activated again and the issue went away. I don't think it's the Nord theme because now the alignment works correctly on both machines. Maybe it was a weird glitch.